# Can't deploy kubernetes dashboard (HTTPS) publicly

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

im new to kubernetes and after researching a long time it seems im running out of resources so I'd be more than glad if somebody could help me.

#### What I currently have

- One Node that i am connecting to via SSH, bare-metal kubernetes setup (Notice that im **not** running k8s in the cloud)
- `kubectl version` yields `1.20` on Client and Server Side
- NGINX Ingress Controller
- Cluster setup with kubeadm
- Following Pods, Services and one ingress resource (dashboard):

**Pods**:

| NAMESPACE | NAME | READY | STATUS | RESTARTS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-admission-create-4ml4p | 0/1 | Completed | 0 | 23m |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-admission-patch-jj9c6 | 0/1 | Completed | 1 | 23m |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-kxwgv | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | coredns-74ff55c5b-2xbvq | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | coredns-74ff55c5b-sc667 | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | etcd-k8s.mydomain.de | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | kube-apiserver-k8s.mydomain.de | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | kube-controller-manager-k8s.mydomain.de | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | kube-flannel-ds-fhzzp | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | kube-proxy-lq7tt | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kube-system | kube-scheduler-k8s.mydomain.de | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b59f7d4df-v6qsn | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-5x4nd | 1/1 | Running | 0 | 23m |

**Services**:

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TYPE | CLUSTER-IP | EXTERNAL-IP | PORT(S) | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | kubernetes | ClusterIP | 10.96.0.1 | none | 443/TCP | 33d |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller | NodePort | 10.98.67.34 | none | 80:32346/TCP, 443:30710/TCP | 33d |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | ClusterIP | 10.110.196.58 | none | 443/TCP | 33d |
| kube-system | kube-dns | ClusterIP | 10.96.0.10 | none | 53/UDP,53/TCP, 9153/TCP | 33d |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | ClusterIP | 10.109.128.22 | none | 8000/TCP | 33d |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard | ClusterIP | 10.98.158.159 | none | 443/TCP | 33d |

**Ingress Resource** (Dashboard):

| NAMESPACE | NAME | CLASS | HOSTS | ADDRESS | PORTS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-ingress |  | dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de | 10.10.1.164 | 80 | 52m |

When I try to reach the kubernetes dashboard using `https://dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de` nothing happens. When I try to reach it using `https://dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de:30710`, which is the HTTPS TCP Port of the nginx ingress controller, then it works. Its a non secure connection and the browser warns me, but it works. But obviously this is not the desired behavior.

#### What i want to have

I want to deploy the kubernetes dashboard in a way so that `https://dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de` gives access to the kubernetes dashboard over HTTPS. I don't know why this is currently not the case.

These are the configuration `.yaml` files i used for the deployments and stuff:

- NGINX Ingress Controller: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
- Kubernetes Dashboard: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
- Dashboard Ingress Resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Logs of the nginx ingress controller tell me that it registers the ingress resource, so i am confused:

```sh
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.44.0
  Build:         f802554ccfadf828f7eb6d3f9a9333686706d613
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.6
I0323 09:42:57.665847       6 flags.go:208] "Watching for Ingress" class="nginx"
W0323 09:42:57.665953       6 flags.go:213] Ingresses with an empty class will also be processed by this Ingress controller

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0323 09:42:57.667132       6 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0323 09:42:57.667958       6 main.go:241] "Creating API client" host="https://10.96.0.1:443"
I0323 09:42:57.682847       6 main.go:285] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="20" git="v1.20.3" state="clean" commit="01849e73f3c86211f05533c2e807736e776fcf29" platform="linux/amd64"
I0323 09:42:57.997597       6 main.go:105] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0323 09:42:58.003204       6 main.go:115] "Enabling new Ingress features available since Kubernetes v1.18"
W0323 09:42:58.008105       6 main.go:127] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be used.
I0323 09:42:58.033445       6 ssl.go:532] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0323 09:42:58.070414       6 nginx.go:254] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0323 09:42:58.077773       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"a76c1e40-f5aa-4353-aeea-35bccbbb57a7", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"3497961", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0323 09:42:59.183747       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"6f02c931-bfad-44a1-a219-4e2b2970365e", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"3497191", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0323 09:42:59.271684       6 nginx.go:296] "Starting NGINX process"
I0323 09:42:59.271826       6 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0323 09:42:59.272447       6 nginx.go:316] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0323 09:42:59.272851       6 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0323 09:42:59.288414       6 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0323 09:42:59.288501       6 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-kxwgv"
I0323 09:42:59.302119       6 status.go:201] "POD is not ready" pod="ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-kxwgv" node="k8s.mydomain.de"
I0323 09:42:59.307191       6 status.go:281] "updating Ingress status" namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" ingress="dashboard-ingress" currentValue=[{IP:10.10.1.164 Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[]
I0323 09:42:59.315053       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"6f02c931-bfad-44a1-a219-4e2b2970365e", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"3498054", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0323 09:42:59.381846       6 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0323 09:42:59.382014       6 controller.go:174] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0323 09:42:59.382266       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-kxwgv", UID:"2ba6f14e-36a8-401b-a1d8-00921cbe9604", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"3497997", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0323 09:43:59.323910       6 status.go:281] "updating Ingress status" namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" ingress="dashboard-ingress" currentValue=[] newValue=[{IP:10.10.1.164 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0323 09:43:59.333091       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"6f02c931-bfad-44a1-a219-4e2b2970365e", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"3498144", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

When i set up the cluster with microk8s instead of kubeadm it works.
Please specify what I have to do in order to make this work.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run nginx ingress controller in hostNetwork Mode https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network

```
template:
  spec:
    hostNetwork: true
```

And run it as DaemonSet.

And set dnsPolicy to ClusterFirstWithHostNet

Also, please read the security warnings in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network

If you are using https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm then add below to values file

```
controller:
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  hostNetwork: true
  kind: DaemonSet
```

Comment: Ah I think that's why it works when i set the cluster up with `microk8s` - i checked the configs and the nginx-ingress-controller pods IP is the same as the nodes IP, meaning it uses the `hostNetwork`. What would be the alternative? What to do if I don't want the security issues and dont want it to use the hostNetwork? Install `metalLB` LoadBalancer?

Comment: Yes. Please use metal LB. hostNetwork option is only for learning. You just need one LB for your API Server for HA cluster and another for Ingress Controller. Ideally All Services should use ingress controller instead of service of type load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are actually getting at the place of ingress resource :
`dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de`

apart of that in your service : `ingress-nginx-controller` is exposed as `NodePort` it should be as the `LoadBalancer` so that you can get one IP.

You can add that IP in to DNS as A record and map the domain. Inside ingress you can add the domain same you did.

Now for HTTPS you might have to create and store the certificate in `secret` so that Nginx ingress can use the certificate and server the traffic over HTTPS.

if you are using the [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) for auto manging the TLS/SSL certificate ayour ingress will be something like this :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "2000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "2000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: dev-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.example.io
    secretName: dev
```

Comment: `curl https://dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de` yields `Connection refused`, `curl https://dashboard.k8s.mydomain.de` yields SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (curl exit code 77). In the second case and in the browser, i can choose "continue to untrusted page" or something like this and then I'll see the dashboard. About the "NodePort": I've read that setting "LoadBalancer" is only possible/supported when you are running k8s in the cloud, is that true?

Comment: Yes you are right i thought you are running in cloud

Comment: No, its really just a remote server where k8s is running on. I will try with the certificate stuff tho, thank you!